# Ruby: overloading indexed assignment to instance attributes

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

For the instances of a class that I'm writing (an ActiveRecord model), I'd like to be able to overload assignments like this:

```
m.rank['foo'] = 1
m.rank['bar'] = 2
```

In other words, I don't want the numbers to be written into an actual `@rank` hash, but rather I'd like to have some setter method called with `'foo'` and `1` as its parameters.

A naive way to get this functionality would be to define `set_rank(key, rank)` and `get_rank(key)`, but the syntax isn't very sugary.  For nicer syntax, one could define a helper class that defines `[]` and `[]=`, and have the `rank` method return an instance of that class.

Is there an established pattern to write this in a concise manner?  Or is it a bad idea in the first place, and I should just use `set_rank` and `get_rank`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by initialising your rank attribute like so:

```
@rank = {}

def @rank.[] key
    puts "Retrieving key #{key}" #put code to execute when key is retrieved here
    begin
        self.fetch key
    rescue
        puts "Key not found" #put code to execute when key is not found here
        nil
    end
end

def @rank.[]= key, val
    puts "Setting key #{key} to #{val}" #put code to execute when key is set here
    self.store key, val
end
```

You will need to do this in your `initialize` method and use `attr_reader :rank` (recommended) or  `attr_accessor :rank`.

**Explanation**

This uses a feature of Ruby called singleton methods. Singleton methods are where you define methods on specific objects rather than on all instances of a class. You can define singleton methods on any object. The syntax is, as above, `def identifier.method ... end`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty ugly and totally useless. My solution:

```
class Test
    attr_accessor :rank

    def initialize
        @rank = Rank.new
    end

    def meth(key, rank)
        print key, " ", rank
    end 

    class Rank
        def []=(key, rank)
            @test = Test.new
            @test.meth(key, rank)
        end
    end

end

m = Test.new
m.rank["key"] = "rank" # => key rank
```